# how to get previous page url when javascript is disabled?

Tags: html, noscript

How to get the previous URL when Javascript is disabled?
The page URL from where it is redirected?
The solution should be working fine in all browsers?

Comment: the back button? but seriously what do you need to do with the previous url if js is disabled

Answer (score 0):

For a client side, imho there is only the JS solution.

```
var x = document.referrer;
```

But you can always use the PHP solution, if that is an option for you, the referer is part of the SERVER super array:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>
```

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I can only advise to look at $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] in php.
But you should read about moments and specialties of using it.